# Check if collection contains element with specific properties

Tags: c#, linq, equals, contains

I have 2 collections with different entities. How to make from them 1 collection with unique data (companyName & productName & certId).

What i try is :
1st collection i iterate in loop and check if 2nd collection contains element with the same certId, productName and companyName. But i not sure if i make it good.

If element doesn't contains, i need to add it.

```
releases.ForEach(
            r =>
            {
                if (!ratings.All(x =>
                    x.certID == r.certID && x.companyNameWhenRated == r.companyNameOnStore &&
                    x.productNameWhenRated == r.productNameOnStore))
                {
                    ratings.ToList().Add(new uRating
                                         {
                                             certID = r.certID,
                                             productNameWhenRated = r.productNameOnStore,
                                             companyNameWhenRated = r.companyNameOnStore,
                                             uCert = r.uCert,
                                             rAgeRating = r.uCert.uRatings
                                                 .Where(u => u.certID == r.certID
                                                             && u.productNameWhenRated != r.productNameOnStore
                                                             && u.companyNameWhenRated != r.companyNameOnStore)
                                                 .Select(ur => ur.rAgeRating).First()
                                         });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why are you not sure if it's good? Have you tried running it? Is there an error? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: create a method bool HasSpecificProperties(object o); then check like this collection.Any(HasSpecificProperties)

Comment: @eddie_cat, every collection i get from db. `releases` have 2 elements and `ratings` - 17 elements, which aren't the same. So after this operation i expect to have 19 elements in collection

Comment: Do the two collections contain the same type of elements?

Comment: @Magnus, no, 2 collections with different entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (!ratings.All(...))` means all the ratings have to match the release, which is not what you want.  Use `if(!ratings.Any(...))` which means any of the ratings has to match the release.